# Extracting features from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe like this

```
    ID  Phone          ex

0   1   5333371000     533
1   2   5354321938     535
2   3   3840812        384
3   4   5451215        545
4   5   2125121278     212
```

For example if "ex" start to 533,535,545 new variable should be :

Sample output :

```
   ID    Phone         ex          iswhat

0   1   5333371000     533         personal
1   2   5354321938     535         personal
2   3   3840812        384         notpersonal
3   4   5451215        545         personal
4   5   2125121278     212         notpersonal
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: @jsotola No it's not.  The expected output has a new column called `iswhat`.

Comment: What do you mean by `start to`. What is the datatype of `ex` column? str or int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['iswhat'] = np.where(df['ex'].isin([533, 535, 545]), 'personal', 'not personal')
print(df)

# Output
   ID       Phone   ex        iswhat
0   1  5333371000  533      personal
1   2  5354321938  535      personal
2   3     3840812  384  not personal
3   4     5451215  545      personal
4   5  2125121278  212  not personal
```

**Update**

You can also use your `Phone` column directly:

```
df['iswhat'] = np.where(df['Phone'].astype(str).str.match('533|535|545'), 
                        'personal', 'not personal')
```

Note: If `Phone` column contains strings you can safely remove `.astype(str)`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `np.where` along with `str.contains`:

```py
df["iswhat"] = np.where(df["ex"].str.contains(r'^(?:533|535|545)$'),
                        'personal', 'notpersonal')
```

Comment: Instead of `contains`, you can also use `.str.fullmatch(r'(533|535|545)')`. +1

Comment: @Corralien I also saw in your answer you think that the extensions are numbers.  I guess the OP will let us know at some point whether it is text or number.